# reading zip files within tar file

Tags: python, zip, tar

I am trying to extract some xml files within zipped files, from a tar file. Actually, there is a large tar file, in which there are multiple "zip" files. Each zipfile contains another zipfile with the xml file.

```
import tarfile, os
import sys
from zipfile import ZipFile

os.chdir("C://.../temp/foo")
tar = tarfile.open("C://....")
for member in tar.getmembers():
    if member.name.endswith(".zip"):
        f=tar.extractfile(member)
        content=ZipFile(f, 'r')
        content = content.extract(content)
        tar.close()
```

The script above the not extract the good file

Comment: How does it fail? Do you get an error message?

Comment: the `f` object is an `ExFileObject`. The name of this `ExFileObject` is the same as the name of the `tarfile`. This is why a `KeyError` is raised: `There is no item named <zipfile.ZipFile file=<ExFileObject name='C:/....tar'> mode='r'> in the archive`

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a bit of manipulation to get the second ZipFile into a ZipFile rather than a ZipExtFile, as you would have noticed.

The key thing is that the second-level ZipFile has to be instantiated out of a bytestream object, and then it will behave properly.  I created a test file with your spec and it works fine (tar - zip - zip - textfile) and if you have deeper levels of zipfile nesting you can just generalise the code some more.

```
import tarfile
from zipfile import ZipFile
import io

mytar = tarfile.open('mytar.tar')
print('Opening tar file, members:')
for member in mytar.getnames():
    print('>%s'%member)
    if member.endswith('zip'):
        # get the tarfile object
        tf = mytar.extractfile(member)
        # this is what the first-lelvel ZipFile will be
        with ZipFile(tf) as myzip1:
            print(myzip1.namelist())
            # now let's get at those second-level ZipFiles, which currently exist as ZipExtFile 
            for zipfile2name in myzip1.namelist():
                # read the file into bytes
                zipfile2bytes = myzip1.read(zipfile2name)
                # get a bytestream
                f = io.BytesIO(zipfile2bytes)
                # now instantiate a ZipFile Object
                zipfile2 = ZipFile(f)
                # now we can use it like a proper ZipFile
                print(zipfile2.namelist())
                for textfile in zipfile2.namelist():
                    with zipfile2.open(textfile) as myfile:
                        print(myfile.read())


print('--finished--')
mytar.close()
```

Comment: Note - this was tested on Linux with Python 3.5.2

Comment: your script seems good. However it raises the same error : a `BadZipFile`. The source of error is `mytar.extractfile(member)` where the `member`, don't know why, is kept as the `tar` file

Comment: this is how it looks in my terminal: formatting doesn't work in comments :(

Comment: marcin@ubuntu:~/Documents/stackoverflow/ziptar$ python3 zipper.py 
Opening tar file, members:
>za.zip
['z1.zip']
['file1.txt']
b'This is file 1\n'
>zb.zip
['z2.zip']
['file2.txt']
b'This is file 2\n'
>zc.zip
['z3.zip']
['file3.txt']
b'This is file 3\n'
>zd.zip
['z4.zip']
['file4.txt']
b'This is file 4\n'
--finished--

Comment: if you can throw me your actual file, I can test that, but it works on Linux/py3.5.2 and Win/py3.6.2 based on my test file.  what version of python are you using?

Comment: So did you find an answer? If so please publish it.

Comment: If you can share a representative file it would help with troubleshooting